# What are the rules for the precision of casting operations in GLSL

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, mali

I have a GL_R16UI texture in OpenGL ES 3.0 on an Android device (Google Pixel 6). I'm then drawing a screen rect, and copying the texture to the RGBA8 output using the following fragment shader:

```c
uniform mediump usampler2D texture_sampler;
in highp vec2 texcoords;
out lowp vec4 out_color;
void main() {
    mediump uint v = texture(texture_sampler, vec2(0.5, 0.5)).r;
    highp float v2 = float(v);  // need temporary for android
    out_color = vec4(v2 / 65535.0, 0, 0, 1);
    // out_color = vec4(float(v) / 65535.0, 0, 0, 1); // works only on desktop
}
```

`v` is set to 120 * 256.
no errors are shown for `vec4(float(v) / 65535.0, ..`, the result simply goes to 0.
it also goes to zero when i replace `highp float v2` with `mediump float v2`.

- What are the rules of casting? Which precision will a float(v) without temporary yield?
- Why is it, that using `mediump float v2` yields a 0? I would think that mediump should be enough to yield something != 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max value of a 16-bit float is `65504.0`. The divisor for `x/65535.0` is `x/+INF` in fp16, so you get zero.

> // works only on desktop

Desktop is probably ignoring the `mediump` and giving you fp32 anyway.

Comment: thanks, that explains a lot.

is it in the gl standard, that saying float(v), where v is a mediump uint, will yield a mediump float? does it depend on vertex vs fragment shader? (similar code works in the vertex shader).

Comment: "In cases where operands do not have a precision qualifier, the precision qualification will come from the other operands. If no operands have a precision qualifier, then the precision qualifications of the operands of the next consuming operation in the expression will be used. This rule can be applied recursively until a precision qualified operand is found. If necessary, it will also include the precision qualification of l-values for assignments, of the declared variable for initializers, of formal parameters for function call arguments, or of return types for function return values."

Comment: ^ OpenGL ES 3.2 Shader language spec wording